# How to play three KO replays in a row?

Tags: fight-night-champion

I'm playing [Fight Night Champion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Night_Champion) online, a boxing game, on the PS3.

Usually, after a KO, there's a brief replay showing the last punch.

But some online players turn that single replay into three replays with different angles and play them full one after another when they knock you out, with the only purpose to troll.

What key or combination of keys do I need to press to play these three KO replays as well?

Sometimes I manage to catch them later in the fight, and I would like to give them a taste of their own medicine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mystery solved. Finally another PS3 player answered my question via the PSN message system:

> circle button after knock down wait for each knock down to press circle
>   again

I've tried it and it works, it's the circle button: It changes the camera when pressed.

You can play with this unlimited times in single player, while in multiplayer - for obvious reasons - you can only do it for three replays max.

I feel a bit dumb now, it was just the PS3 circle button... In my defence, circle button is not much needed in this game.